# Can a number be both a string, and an integer simultaneously?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to understand a line of code in a problem set provided by CS50. Herein lies the issue:

1. can a number both be simultaneously a string an an integer? Isn't a string traditionally considered to be a string of letters (i.e a word etc? or a paragraph)?
2. if a number can be both a string and an integer, what is the use of differentiating it? Particularly in the line of code below.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_positive_int(string prompt);

int main(void)
{
  int i = get_positive_int("Positive Integer: ");
  printf("%i\n", i);

}

// Prompt user for positive integer 
int get_positive_int (string prompt)
{
   int n; 
  do
  {
    n = get_int("%s", prompt);
  }
  while (n <0 || n > 8);
  return n;
}
```

Comment: why not do the following: function 1: int get _positive_int (int prompt) instead of              
                                        function 2: int get_positive_int (string prompt)

Comment: Prompt is a string like "Please enter an integer".

Answer (score 1):

"No!" a variable can't have multiple data types. This may be possible but only with the representation context. For Example:

```
String a= "1";
Int b=1;
```

1)We can print both variables and both will give us the same output.

2)We can perform calculations on the second one but to perform calculations on the string, you may need to convert it into number format - either int, double or float.

I saw your follow up question. The difference between these two functions is clear with my second point. You have to pass a string value to the function `int get_positive_int(string prompt)`. But in the case of `int get_positive_int(int prompt)`, you may have to pass an integer value to this function. Both these functions will return an integer value. It depends what you are doing inside the function.

For the function `int get_positive_integer(string prompt)`, you may get a string from the user and convert it into an integer, then return that integer value.

Comment: Hey there thanks for your very comprehensive reply. Just a quick question on the following line of code:                                                                                                
int i = get_positive_int("Positive Integer: ");                                                                    ( Qn: If positive integer is a string, then why is it stored as an int? why not write the code as string i = get_string("Positive Integer: ");

Comment: i = get_string("Positive Integer: "); will give you a string value, and if you need to do some calculations, you may need to convert it to an integer every time. This will depend upon the situation that what you need, an integer or an int. The difference between these two is already explained in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is "no". A number can have one of several C types (e.g. `int`, `double`, ...), but only one of them, and `string` is not a numeric type.

I'm not sure what's unclear to you about the code.

Comment: Could i have a follow up question.                                                                               
why not do the following:                                                                                             function 1: int get _positive_int (int prompt)                   instead of                                      function 2: int get_positive_int (string prompt)

Comment: @LimDion Because then the call `get_positive_int("Positive Integer: ")` would be a type error: `"Positive Integer: "` is a string, not an integer.

Comment: "*and `string` is not a numeric type.*" in fact it isn't an intrinsic C type at all.

Comment: @LimDion: "*why not do the following:* why would you want to do this?

Comment: @alk True. It's provided by `<cs50.h>` as an alias for `char *`, I believe.

Comment: I don't know much about CS50, but this is not the first time I've seen their "`string`" typedef cause confusion.  It adds significantly more confusion than convenience, I fear.